# Query returning empty set in script, works in PHPMyAdmin and on local version

Tags: php, mysql, oop

This has been plaguing me for hours now. This code works perfectly on my local machine, and the query executes in phpmyadmin, etc.

I have the following code:

```
 <?php

    class db {
        public $server = 'localhost';
        public $user = '***';
        public $passwd = '***';
        public $db = '***';
        public $dbCon;

        function __construct(){
            $this->dbCon = mysqli_connect($this->server, $this->user, $this->passwd, $this->db);
        }

        function __destruct(){
            mysqli_close($this->dbCon);
        }

        private function getFileTree($catID) {

            $sql = "SELECT
                        *
                    FROM
                        table_name
                    WHERE
                            cat_id = ".$catID;

            $results = mysqli_query($this->dbCon, $sql);


            return $results;
        }



    }

$db = new db();

$cat_id = 1;

$data = $db->getFileTree($cat_id);

echo json_encode($data);


?>
```

I'm stumped because the query looks fine, it runs in PHPMyadmin, and the script works fine on my local version but once I moved to server it just returns an empty array. Only thing I can think is its something to do with older php version on the server, but still seems like it should work, all my other queries are working fine.

Also when I var_dump $results, I get the following when trying one cat_id in the db:

```
NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL array(1) { [""]=> NULL }
```

and the following when I try the other cat_id:

```
object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(6) ["lengths"]=> NULL ["num_rows"]=> int(24) ["type"]=> int(0) } [null]
```

Comment: what result are you getting? 0 results. an error?

Comment: Is it an empty array, or is it maybe just false or null? Make sure you have turned on error reporting and set it to a proper level.

Comment: See my edit. I turned on error reporting and im not getting any errors. When I do the echo json_encode($data) it's just printing [null]

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of `$subjectID?`. It seems you have to give `$catID` instead of `$subjectID`

Answer (score 0):

The Manual says:

> For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries
>   mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object

Try

```
$rows = $results->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

var_dump($rows);
```